# C Language: Comparing words in two arrays and removing common words

Tags: arrays, c, duplicates

I was wondering if anyone could give me some advice RE the problem I am encountering. The below code reads a pre-written 'input file' (named "input" in my code) and then copies its contents and creates a new file (called "output1" in my code).

I am wanting to compare this "output1" array (ch) against a "stopword" array (stop) and remove all common words, and create a new "output2" file with the results.

How would I go about this? My code currently is posted below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *read;
    FILE *write;
    FILE *stopword;
    char ch[100];
    char stop[100];

    read = fopen("input.dat", "r");           
    write = fopen("output1.dat", "w");          
    stopword = fopen("stopword.dat", "r");      
    while (fgets(ch, 100, read))            
    { 
        fputs(ch, write);                    
        printf("%s", ch);                   
    } 
    printf("\n");
    while (fgets(stop, 100, stopword))          
    {
        printf("%s", stop);
    }
    fclose(read);                           
    fclose(write);                           
    fclose(stopword);
    return 0;
}
```

the contents of **input.dat** are:

```
In this program, you are hoping to remove the common words.
A result there should display something which will remove all of common words,
and can be placed in a new output2 file.
```

The contents of **stopword.dat** are:

```
in this you are to the a there which will of and can be
```

desired **output2.dat** should read:

```
program hoping remove common words result should display something remove all common words placed new output2 file
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you should clarify what you want help with.  `fgets(ch, 100, read)`  reads 100 bytes in but you probably want to read a word at a time.  Personally, I would read both input files into memory.  For example using stat to find file size, then allocate a sufficiently large buffer.  If you sort your stop words, then you can binary search for it instead of linear search.

Comment: Presumably the files contain one word per line.  Note that `fgets` will include the line terminator (if present), so you should probably be explicitly removing a trailing newline from these strings.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps you should implement:

- read the list of stop words one word at a time. For each word:

  - store a copy into an array of strings in memory.
- read the input file one word at a time. For each word:

  - output the word to **output1.dat**
  - if the word is not found in the list of stop words, output the word to **output2.dat**
- done.

To read a single word at a time, you could use `fscanf()`, but punctuation present in the file **input.dat** will be considered part of the words by `fscanf`'s `%s` conversion. Hence I recommend reading one byte at a time and detect words as sequences of letters, digits and dashes.